# How to see if a string exists in a huge (>19GB) sorted file?

Tags: sorting, unix, grep

I have files that can be 19GB or greater, they will be huge but sorted. Can I use the fact that they are sorted to my advantage when searching to see if a certain string exists?
I looked at something called sgrep but not sure if its what I'm looking for. An example is I will have a 19GB text file with millions of rows of

ABCDEFG,1234,Jan 21,stackoverflow

and I want to search just the first column of these millions of row to see if ABCDEFG exists in this huge text file.
Is there a more efficient way then just greping this file for the string and seeing if a result comes. I don't even need the line, I just need almost a boolean, true/false if it is inside this file

Comment: How many lookups do you have to do? The best way of doing this will depend on whether you need to look up one key, or a million keys.

Comment: And are you always going to be searching against the leading field of a line?  That may impact how the sort order can be leveraged.

Comment: Are you going to be doing lots of lookups against static data? Or few lookups against changing data?

Comment: The number of lookups will vary, it can be up to 100k. It will always be leading field of the line, I am going to be sorting these files using linux sort prior though so I figure I should be using sorted files to my advantage, not sure if I can. The list will then stay static, no changing.

Answer (score 4):

Actually sgrep is what I was looking for. The reason I got confused was because structured grep has the same name as sorted grep and I was installing the wrong package. sgrep is amazing

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to sgrep (sorted).  That looks like a handy tool!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there are any utilities that would help you out if the box, but it would be pretty straight forward to write an application specific to your problem. A binary search would work well, and should yield your result within 20-30 queries against the file.

Let's say your lines are never more than 100 characters, and the file is B bytes long.

Do something like this in your favorite language:

```
sub file_has_line(file, target) {
  a = 0
  z = file.length

  while (a < z) {
    m = (a+z)/2
    chunk = file.read(m, 200)  
        // That is, read 200 bytes, starting at m.
    line = chunk.split(/\n/)[2] 
        // split the line on newlines, and keep only the second line.
    if line < target
      z = m - 1
    else 
      a = m + 1
  }

  return (line == target)
}
```

If you're only doing a single lookup, this will *dramatically* speed up your program.  Instead of reading ~20 GB, you'll be reading ~20 KB of data.

You could try to optimize this a bit by extrapolating that "Xerox" is going to be at 98% of the file and starting the midpoint there...but unless your need for optimization is quite extreme, you really won't see much difference.  The binary search will get you that close within 4 or 5 passes, anyway.

If you're doing lots of lookups (I just saw your comment that you will be), I would look to pump all that data into a database where you can query at will.

Answer (score 0):

So if you're doing 100,000 lookups, but this is a one-and-done process where having it in a database has no ongoing value, you could take another approach...

Sort your list of targets, to match the sort order of the log file.  Then walk through each in parallel.  You'll still end up reading the entire 20 GB file, but you'll only have to do it once and then you'll have all your answers.  Something like this:

```
sub file_has_lines(file, target_array) {
  target_array = target_array.sort
  target = ''
  hits = []

  do {
    if line < target
      line = file.readln()
    elsif line > target
      target = target_array.pop()
    elseif line == target
      hits.push(line)
      line = file.readln()
  } while not file.eof()

  return hits
}
```

Comment: I think if 100,000 invocations of sgrep meet your needs, run with it and never look back.  However, if that's taking too long, give this answer a try, as you'll get all your answers in one pass.

Comment: I was thinking that reading the entire 20 GB file would be burdensome..but if you're already committed to sorting the file, one more pass to read the results will be insignificant.